# Ant is not replacing multiple instances in the same line

Tags: java, regex, replace, ant

I'm using replaceregexp to replace a particular match in files. Whenever there are multiple matches in a single line it is only replacing the last instance of the line.

```
Eg:
Input:
    f1.lblTest.text != null && f1.lblTest.text != ""
Reg EX:
 <replaceregexp file="mod1.js" match="(.*)f1(\.|\[&quot;)lblTest(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;)(.*)" replace="\1f1\2lblTestNew\3\4 \\/\\/Modified" flags="g">
Expected Output:
    f1.lblTestNew.text != null && f1.lblTestNew.text != "" //Modified
Actual Output:
    f1.lblTest.text != null && f1.lblTestNew.text != "" //Modified
With this <replaceregexp file="mod1.js" match="f1(\.|\[&quot;)$lblTest(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;)" replace="f1\1lblTestNew\2 \\/\\/Modified" flags="g"> I'm getting the below output
f1.lblTestNew. //Modifiedtext != null && f1.lblTestNew. //Modifiedtext != "".
 With this <replaceregexp file="mod1.js" match="f1(\.|\[&quot;)$lblTest(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;)" replace="f1\1lblTestNew\2" flags="g"> I'm getting the below output
f1.lblTestNew.text != null && f1.lblTestNew.text != "" This is ok but I really wanted a comment that lets the users know that this is modified and if they want they can modify again.
```

Please suggest any solutions.

Note:I tried g,m,s flags with and without 'byline' already and they didn't work.

Comment: It happens because of `(.*)` on both sides. Remove them and the backreferences in the replacement pattern. Try `<replaceregexp file="mod1.js" match="f1(\.|\[&quot;)$lblTest(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;)" replace="f1\1lblTestNew\2 \\/\\/Modified" flags="g">`

Comment: Hi Wiktor thanks for your suggestion, with your changes I got this output `f1.lblTestNew. //Modifiedtext != null && f1.lblTestNew. //Modifiedtext != "". `. I understood why `(.*)` is causing the problem. I wanted the //Modified only once at the end of the line. If I remove the ` \\/\\/Modified` it is replacing correctly and the output is `f1.lblTeststudio1.text != null && f1.lblTeststudio1.text != ""`,but I want to have `//Modified` so that we know that it is modified by the Ant script which is useful for the users so the users can modify manually again if they want. Any suggestions?

Comment: I understand now, that you want to replace multiple occ. of some texts *and* add text at the end. Looks tricky, don't you think? Can't you use my suggestion with `f1\1lblTestNew\2` as replacement string and then append the `//Modified` comment with another rule, say `(.*f1(\.|\[&quot;)lblTestNew(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;).*)` and replace with `\1 // Modified`?

Comment: Hi Wiktor thanks again for the response, I already tried that (first appending the comment and then replacement) yesterday but the problem with that is there will be two operations(regex's) on each file and for each match, which will be time consuming for files with huge number of lines and with huge number of files. So I'm looking for a single operation which can serve both.

Comment: No way, it is impossible, you cannot use a Java or JavaScript regex with conditional replacement pattern. Only Boost and PCRE2 allow that. *If* the text (`//Modified`) is present in the strings, then,  I think we could help that, but not in the case when it is missing from the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have [no conditional replacement pattern support in Ant `replaceregexp`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html), there is only one possible solution involving 2 steps:

- `<replaceregexp file="mod1.js" match="f1(\.|\[&quot;)$lblTest(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;)" replace="f1\1lblTestNew\2" flags="g">` to replace all the `lblTest` with `lblTestNew` texts
- Append the `//Modified` substring to the end of the strings, say, with `<replaceregexp file="mod1.js" match="(.*f1(\.|\[&quot;)lblTestNew(\.|&quot;\]|\[&quot;).*)" replace="\1 // Modified">`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, Finally I had to follow this 2-steps process.